# CSS add font-face not work for style print pdf

Tags: html, css, font-face

I doing print div content to PDF
I have style CSS in page, style view in web content is working fine but content in PDF seen not work.

```
<style type="text/css" media="screen, print">
        
        @media print {
            @font-face {
                font-family: 'Tacteing';
                src:url('font/TACTENG.TTF')  format('truetype');
            }
        }
        @media screen {
            @font-face {
                font-family: 'Tacteing';
                src:url('font/TACTENG.TTF')  format('truetype');
            }}
 </style>
```

and my HTML code :

```
<p style="font-family:Tacteing;">3</p>
```

Note: CSS style in page
and result in web is working fine but when i click button print my PDF still show `3`

Answer (score -1):

Try `!important` tag for your font family. Once upon a time, it's work for me.

```
@media print {
        @font-face {
            font-family: 'Tacteing' !important;
            src:url('font/TACTENG.TTF')  format('truetype');
        }
    }
    @media screen {
        @font-face {
            font-family: 'Tacteing' !important;
            src:url('font/TACTENG.TTF')  format('truetype');
        }}
```

Comment: `!important` is a hack to be used during developing. It's like turning on _cheat mode_. Which is absolutely fine when you're testing things during development phase. But it's not a production solution for anything.